# Не могу получить нужный результат из переменной

Tags: python, циклы, случайные-числа, генераторы

понадобился простой генератор паролей.

````
```
import random
symbols = '!#$%&*+-0123456789<=>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
num = input('how passwd gen?' + "/n")#Вводим кол-во генерируемых паролей
len = input('how symb gen?' + "/n")#вводим кол-во символов
num = int(num)
len = int(len)
for n in range(num):
    password=''
for i in range(len):
    password += random.choice(symbols)
print(password)
```
````

Эта конструкция работает и генерирует столько паролей, сколько нужно, но разово. Я же хочу чтобы программа выполнялась заново. Пробую конструкцию:

````
```
import random
def main()
symbols = '!#$%&*+-0123456789<=>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
num = input('how passwd gen?' + "/n")#Вводим кол-во генерируемых паролей
len = input('how symb gen?' + "/n")#вводим кол-во символов
num = int(num)
len = int(len)
for n in range(num):
    password=''
    for i in range(len):
        password += random.choice(symbols)
print(password) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```
````

Она работает, но генерирует только один пароль, когда мне нужно например 3 или 5. Не могу понять, где ошибаюсь.

Comment: А цикл по len у вас с неправильным отступом в оригинале или просто тут при вставке сломалось?

Comment: Видимо тут сломалось

Comment: Если "тут сломалось", то отредактируйте вопрос и исправьте отступы.И пишите вопросы в input по-русски, потому как по-английски у вас полный "МГИМО финишед"...

Answer (score 0):

Вам это нужно?

```
import random

symbols = '!#$%&*+-0123456789<=>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
num = int(input('how passwd gen?'))  #Вводим кол-во генерируемых паролей
len = int(input('how symb gen?'))    #вводим кол-во символов

passwords = []

for n in range(num):
    password = ''
    for i in range(len):
        password += random.choice(symbols)
    passwords.append(password)

print(passwords)
```

вот так код покомпактнее выглядит:

```
passwords = []

for n in range(num):
    password = ''.join([random.choice(symbols) for x in range(len)])
    passwords.append(password)
```

а вот так еще покомпактнее, правда и понепонятнее :)

```
passwords = [''.join([random.choice(symbols) for pos in range(len)]) for count in range(num)]
```

**P.S.**

кстати называть переменные ключевыми словами не лучшая идея

```
pass=''
```

Comment: Не совсем. Этот код работает. Если он не обернут в конструкцию def main()...while True, то он генерирует то, что мне нужно. т.е например 4 пароля по 12 символов. Но когда я ее заворачиваю в def main()  генерируется только один пароль

Comment: Да, переменные используются password. Поправил тут

Comment: @Nickolay, приведите код как ваш main выглядит и как именно вы его вызываете - у меня получился нормальный бесконечный цикл

Comment: С циклом тоже нет проблем, проблема в том, что я хочу получать в каждый цикл то кол-во паролей, которое я передал в переменную num, а получаю только один